# Error when programmatically transitioning view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using this code to transition view controllers after the user logs in:

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesVC") as! messagesViewController
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code does not raise any errors when I am in the editor, however when it runs nothing happens and I am returned with this error:

> 2015-11-19 12:06:08.835 collaboration[8788:70890] Warning: Attempt to
>   present   on
>    which is already
>   presenting

The view controller 'messagesViewController' exists, and it's storyboard scene has the identifier 'messagesVC'. I am stumped on what is wrong... If you know please help me out.
Thanks 
Login button:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let savedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")! as String
        if savedUsername == "" {
        if usernameInput.text != "" && passwordInput.text != "" {
            let usernameTextFieldString = usernameInput.text! as String
            let passwordTextFieldString = passwordInput.text! as String
            let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/bubble/login.php?username=\(usernameTextFieldString)&password=\(passwordTextFieldString)&secretKey=kjdfb4u7bksSDDF44wlksdnw33j4")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        let userInfo = responseString!.componentsSeparatedByString("9254203598")
                        let userInfoCount = userInfo.count
                        if userInfoCount == 4 {
                            let userInfoId = userInfo[1] as String
                            let userInfoUsername = userInfo[2] as String
                            let userInfoPassword = userInfo[3] as String
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userInfoId, forKey: "id")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userInfoUsername, forKey: "username")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userInfoPassword, forKey: "password")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                            let keyId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("id")
                            let keyUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")
                            let keyPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("password")
                            if keyId != nil && keyUsername != nil && keyPassword != nil {
                                self.sendAlert("Success", message: "You have been logged in successfully")
                                self.usernameInput.text = ""
                                self.passwordInput.text = ""
                                self.loginStatus()
                    //VIEW CONTROLLER TRANSITION TO FIX
                                let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesVC") as! messagesViewController
                                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        } else {
                            self.sendAlert("Error", message: "Unable to login")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            loginStatus()
        } else {
            sendAlert("Login Invalid", message: "The username and password you entered are not associated with an account")
        }
        } else {
            self.sendAlert("Error", message: "You must be logged in to log out")
        }
    }
```

Revised code:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let savedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")! as String
        if savedUsername == "" {
        if usernameInput.text != "" && passwordInput.text != "" {
            let usernameTextFieldString = usernameInput.text! as String
            let passwordTextFieldString = passwordInput.text! as String
            let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/bubble/login.php?username=\(usernameTextFieldString)&password=\(passwordTextFieldString)&secretKey=kjdfb4u7bksSDDF44wlksdnw33j4")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
                    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        print(responseString)
                        let userInfo = responseString!.componentsSeparatedByString("9254203598")
                        let userInfoCount = userInfo.count
                        if userInfoCount == 4 {
                            let userInfoId = userInfo[1] as String
                            let userInfoUsername = userInfo[2] as String
                            let userInfoPassword = userInfo[3] as String
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userInfoId, forKey: "id")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userInfoUsername, forKey: "username")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userInfoPassword, forKey: "password")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                            let keyId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("id")
                            let keyUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")
                            let keyPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("password")
                            if keyId != nil && keyUsername != nil && keyPassword != nil {
                                self.sendAlert("Success", message: "You have been logged in successfully")
                                self.usernameInput.text = ""
                                self.passwordInput.text = ""
                                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")
                                //self.loginStatus()
                                //VIEW CONTROLLER TRANSITION TO FIX
                                let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("messagesVC") as! messagesViewController
                                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Unable to login")
                            //self.sendAlert("Error", message: "Unable to login")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            //loginStatus()
        } else {
            //sendAlert("Login Invalid", message: "The username and password you entered are not associated with an account")
        }
        } else {
            //sendAlert("Error", message: "You must be logged in to log out")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling that code?  Are you calling it while a view controller is being presented, or just before?  We need more context.

Comment: I am calling it after the user has entered text into two text fields, and pressed the 'login' button. Is this what you need? Thanks

Comment: Yes, post the full action of the login button please.

Comment: Not enough room in the comment box. Can I email it to you?

Comment: Use the edit link on your question.

Comment: Added to the question. Thanks

Comment: What is the class of `self` when you execute the `self.presentViewController` line?

Comment: i don't know man, XCode told me to put self before that. The class of the whole code is ViewController. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things that could be the culprit:

You're calling `self.sendAlert`, which I assume presents a `UIAlertController` on the current view controller before presenting your `messagesVC` controller.  This is happening in serial on the main thread, and it looks like you're presenting the messages controller while the alert is being presented.  Why not wait to show the alert until after the messages view controller has been loaded or present the view controller as a `UIAlertAction` on the alert controller?

Secondly, you're calling a function `self.loginStatus()`.  If you're presenting an alert or any other view controllers in that function, that could also be your issue.

Comment: Login status changes a label on the current view controller. Must I remove this function's interacting with the view controller and remove the self.sendAlert()? Thanks a bunch man

Comment: I would remove `sendAlert()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @NickPitoniak did that help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am still getting the error telling me that I am 'attempting to present a view controller that is already being presented'. Revised code is in my original question. Thank you for your help

Comment: What if you comment out the line where you're presenting the `messagesVC` controller.  Maybe you're presenting another controller somewhere else in your code that's not included in the question.  I know this won't present the `messagesVC` controller, but check if anything else happens after removing that line.

Comment: Nothing appeared in the error box and the view was not transitioned.

Comment: I think you missed commenting out one sendAlert call.  Comment this out: `self.sendAlert("Success", message: "You have been logged in successfully")`.  Then try presenting the messages controller.

Comment: Success! Once I have 15 points I will upvote your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NickPitoniak Glad I was able to help. Please feel free to [mark my answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/242209) if you are satisfied.

Comment: One more question: do you know how to configure separate prepareForSegue functions? I currently have these lines that pass a variable to a view controller, however when I segue to another view it crashes. override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let theVC: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        theVC.receivedString = "true"
    }

Comment: @NickPitoniak you should ask a new question, rather than posting another question and code as a comment.  Don't forget to accept this answer.